# regarding working of raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I inserted raspberry Pi ip adress in putty and then I open x11 then I selected on x11 forwading then all of a sudden some message popped up regarding any "key" change and I didn't see and did yes and then after that When I entered pi as username and then raspberry pi as a password I am getting "www

Comment: sorry it is not www ,I am getting access denied

Comment: Default password is `raspberry`, not `raspberry pi`. If this is what you were using, could you edit the question to correct it please?